# Can I recreate/redesign a peer reviewed journal article findings (giving proper credits to author, journal)into powerpoint and sell it?

Tags: ethics

Can I recreate/redesign a peer reviewed journal article findings (giving proper credits to author, journal) into powerpoint slide and sell it for profit?

Comment: Who should buy it?

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica I know who would buy it. Some people in some countries just want to have a bachelor, master, or even PhD degree (from degree I mean just that piece of paper that shows you have that degree) and don't care if their thesis project is done by somebody else. Even their advisers don't care at all. For these kind of theses, it's enough to just reproduce results of a paper and you would get your degree. Most of the time they give money to somebody else (e.g. ghost writer) to reproduce or fabricate the results of a given paper. It's a really serious business.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but that depends on the copyright holder and on any license that is attached to the work. If there is no license at all, then the answer would be no. But even some permissive licenses have a *no commercial use* clause. If so, again, no.

And note that copyright law isn't universal. It varies from country to country.

And note, again, that it is the words (expression) that is normally covered by copyright, not the underlying ideas. Anyone can write about ideas.

But, another issue is how you would be looked upon if you do this. Some things that are, strictly speaking, legal, are still frowned upon.

Comment: And finally of course the miniscule possibility that this is something anyone would pay for.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, well, yes. That. ;-)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft most of our students would. We have journal club and seminar course at my department, we need to present hot topic papers